# Storing array in session variable and retrieving it using foreach in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This is my code in controller

```
class placeorder_ajax extends CI_controller
{
 function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
 }

//change text to check line endings
//new line endings

function index()
{       
//echo "hii";
//echo "<script>alert('dasdas');</script>";


//unset($_SESSION['cart']);
$data = array('product_id'=>$this->input->post('product_id'),
                'quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'),
                'unit'=>$this->input->post('unit'),
                'unit_rate'=>$this->input->post('unit_rate'));

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);

                    print_r($data);
?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $cart)
{
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($cart); echo "</pre>";
    $product_name = $this->db->query("SELECT product_name FROM product WHERE 
 product_id='".$cart['product_id']."'");
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$product_name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$cart['quantity']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$cart['unit']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$cart['unit_rate']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' rownum='".$i."' class='remove_from_cart'><img  
 src='assets/img/delete.png'/></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
 }
?>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table><?php
  }   
  }
  }
```

I dont know how to store that array in session varialbe in codeigniter and retrieve that using foreach loop? It gives error undefinded variable _SESSION and invalid argument supplied for foreach(). So how do I solve this??

**I am doing this in codeigniter**

**How do I store that array in session varialbe and retrive it using foreach??**

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to store that array in session and how to retrieve that array values using foreach loop

Comment: And what does `can't get it working` mean? Any errors ?

Comment: @KedarB : check here how to store data in session - https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: @Napster I did this $this->session->set_userdata($data); but where do I store that and how do I retrieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your array is an associative array. So, print it as key value pair using foreach loop

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {

  //$key will be product_id, quantity etc
  //$value will be corresponding values
  echo "key: $key<br />value: $value";

  //just for formatting the output
  //this will just insert one more break
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing somthing like this

```
$myarray =  $_POST;
$_SESSION['myarray_insession'] = $myarray;
```

Or

```
$myarray = array('product_id'=>$this->input->post('product_id'),
                'quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'),
                'unit'=>$this->input->post('unit'),
                'unit_rate'=>$this->input->post('unit_rate'));


$_SESSION['myarray_insession'] = $myarray;
```

And then use foreach like

```
foreach($mysession as $row=>$value){

    }
```